# How to assign a SQL subquery to a variable and use it in the same context

Tags: sql, variables, variable-assignment

In this select, I want to get the value of previous month and current month and show 6 columns: OLDVALUE itself ~ OLDVALUE X 28,8% ~ OLDVALUE X 8% ~ CURVALUE itself ~ CURVALUE X 28,8% ~ CURVALUE X 8%

But i have to take the previous month 3 times with the same subquery, as showed below. This way my code will be very very big and with lower performance (I want more information).

Is there a way to assign a "temporary" variable to keep the result of this subquery to use again in the same context, changing it's value row by row like a variable in a loop structure?

Regards.

```
/* == PARAMETERS == */
DECLARE @ANO INT = 2011
DECLARE @MES INT = 7

/* ===================================== SELECT ===================================== */
SELECT FUNC.CHAPA, FUNC.CODSECAO,
        (SELECT VALPROVFER FROM PFHSTPROV (NOLOCK)
          WHERE CHAPA = FUNC.CHAPA
            AND ANO = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN PROV.ANO-1 ELSE PROV.ANO END
            AND MES = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN 12 ELSE PROV.MES-1 END
        ) AS PROVFERMESANT,
        (SELECT VALPROVFER FROM PFHSTPROV (NOLOCK)
          WHERE CHAPA = FUNC.CHAPA
            AND ANO = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN PROV.ANO-1 ELSE PROV.ANO END
            AND MES = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN 12 ELSE PROV.MES-1 END
        )*0.288 AS PROVINSSMESANT,
        (SELECT VALPROVFER FROM PFHSTPROV (NOLOCK)
          WHERE CHAPA = FUNC.CHAPA
            AND ANO = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN PROV.ANO-1 ELSE PROV.ANO END
            AND MES = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN 12 ELSE PROV.MES-1 END
        ) * 0.08 AS PROVFGTSMESANT,
        PROV.VALPROVFER AS PROVFERMES, PROV.VALPROVFER*0.288 AS PROVINSSMES,
        PROV.VALPROVFER*0.08 AS PROVFGTSMES,
 FROM PFUNC FUNC (NOLOCK)
 JOIN PFHSTPROV PROV (NOLOCK) ON FUNC.CHAPA = PROV.CHAPA 
    AND FUNC.CODCOLIGADA = PROV.CODCOLIGADA
WHERE FUNC.CODSITUACAO = 'A'
    AND ANO = @ANO
    AND MES = @MES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT FUNC.CHAPA, FUNC.CODSECAO,
            isnull(PFH.VALPROVFER,0) AS PROVFERMESANT,
            isnull(PFH.VALPROVFER,0)*0.288 AS PROVINSSMESANT,
            isnull(PFH.VALPROVFER,0) * 0.08 AS PROVFGTSMESANT,

            PROV.VALPROVFER AS PROVFERMES, PROV.VALPROVFER*0.288 AS PROVINSSMES,
            PROV.VALPROVFER*0.08 AS PROVFGTSMES,
     FROM PFUNC FUNC (NOLOCK)
     JOIN PFHSTPROV PROV (NOLOCK) ON FUNC.CHAPA = PROV.CHAPA 
        AND FUNC.CODCOLIGADA = PROV.CODCOLIGADA

     LEFT JOIN PFHSTPROV PFH (NOLOCK) on 
                 ( (FUNC.CHAPA = PFH.CHAPA) 
                            AND  PFH.ANO = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN PROV.ANO-1 ELSE PROV.ANO END
                            AND PFH.MES = CASE WHEN (PROV.MES-1 = 0) THEN 12 ELSE PROV.MES-1 END        
                 ) 



    WHERE FUNC.CODSITUACAO = 'A'
        AND ANO = @ANO
        AND MES = @MES
```